# C++ sort deque of class pointers with overloading operator <

Tags: c++

I want to sort a deque of class pointers depends on my overloaded operator < but sort doesn't work correctly.

The program display this:

```
Suit: 1 Number: 1
Suit: 1 Number: 2
...
Suit: 1 Number: 13
Suit: 2 Number: 1
...
```

But after the sort it should be this:

```
Suit: 1 Number: 2
Suit: 1 Number: 3
...
Suit: 1 Number: 13
Suit: 1 Number: 1
Suit: 2 Number: 2
...
```

Here is my code:

```
class CCard
{
private:
    int m_suit;
    int m_number;
public:
    CCard(int suit, int number) : m_suit(suit), m_number(number) {}
ostream& Output(ostream& toStream)
{
    return toStream<<"Suit: "<<m_suit<<" Number: "<<m_number<<endl;
}
    bool operator < (const CCard *card)const
    {
        if(m_suit < card->m_suit) { return true; }
        else if(m_suit > card->m_suit) { return false; }
        else
        {
            if(m_number == card->m_number) { return false; }
            else
            {
                if(m_number == 1) { return false; }
                else if(card->m_number == 1) { return true; }
                else { return m_number < card->m_number; }
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    deque<CCard*> test;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= 13; j++)
        {
            test.push_back(new CCard(i,j));
        }
    }
    sort(test.begin(),test.end());
    for(deque<CCard*>::iterator it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->Output(cout);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Why are you using pointers?  Just use a `std::deque<CCard>` and get rid of using `new`.  Do you perhaps come from a Java background?

Comment: what about the `aaaaaaaaaa`? Is that part of your output or did you deliberately reduce the quality of your question?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Probably hacking around the automatic code-only-question prevention thing.

Comment: @NathanOliver because I need to be with pointers, that's is my task.

Comment: Did you try to add debugging to your `operator<` and see if it was actually working correctly? You would've fairly quickly discovered what was going on...

Comment: @BaummitAugen point is, that this **is** a code-only-question, unless OP writes more text

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well yes, that's why he needed a hack to post it with its current content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sorting an array of pointers, so the compiler uses the built-in comparison for pointers - so you end up sorting in address order.

The `operator <` in your class is ignored, because you're not sorting objects. (If you were it still wouldn't work, because you've defined how to compare an object with a pointer, not an object with an object.)

The best thing to do would be define a proper ordering (`bool operator < (const CCard & card) const`) and sort objects, as @NathanOliver suggested.

If you really want to sort the pointers, you will have to write a function that does the comparison taking two pointers, and pass that explicitly to `sort`.